# Spring transactions with Objectify and Appengine

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am using appengine with Objectify to access my datasource. I use Spring for my business layer. In order to play with data I use the [objectify-appengine-spring factory](https://github.com/marceloverdijk/objectify-appengine-spring).

I would like to use annotation based local transactions. Do you know about an existing implementation which I could plug directly as a spring bean?

I'd really like to avoid the pain of implementing my own transaction provider with thread locals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check LushLife's `ObjectifyTransactionManager` [here](http://code.google.com/p/lushlife/source/browse/trunk/gwt_spring_objectify/src/main/java/ex/objectify/spring/ObjectifyTransactionManager.java?r=2845) or [here](http://pastebin.com/dyTf1J7w).

Spring XML config needed (you can find it [here](http://code.google.com/p/lushlife/source/browse/trunk/gwt_spring_objectify/src/main/java/META-INF/spring/objectify-context.xml?r=2845) or [here](http://pastebin.com/BacrBVk0)):

```
<!-- ObjectifyManager -->
<bean id="objectifyManager" class="ex.objectify.spring.ObjectifyManager">
        <property name="basePackage" value="gso.model" />
</bean>

<!-- ObjectifyFactoryBean -->
<bean id="objectifyFactory" class="ex.objectify.spring.ObjectifyFactoryBean">
        <property name="manager" ref="objectifyManager" />
</bean>

<!-- Custom TransactionManager implementation -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="ex.objectify.spring.ObjectifyTransactionManager">
        <property name="manager" ref="objectifyManager" />
</bean>

<!-- Necesary to enable use of @Transactional in your services -->
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

Don't forget to annotate your transactional methods or classes with [@Transactional](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html).

Special thanks to author of this [project](http://code.google.com/p/lushlife/).

Comment: Oh! Interesting ;) Can you post an example of the configuration (xml) and usage of the transaction manager?

Comment: I was searching how to integrate spring & objectify and found this TransactionManager (it's not mine!). Browsing project's source code you can see that is used like any other one, using classical Spring `@Transactional` support approach. I'm going to update my answer with this information.

Comment: força barça? o força catalunya ? :P

Answer (score 0):

I guess the solution works only for Objectify3.

Any solution where I can use transaction attributes (MANDATORY, REQUIRED etc.) in Spring AOP + Objectify4 transactions - XML or Annotation?

Moreover, API docs for Objectify4 still mentions use of the **ObjectifyFactory** method **beginTransaction()** which I guess is not available anymore. It creates confusion for beginners. Would be more useful if the docs are updated to reflect the latest behavior. I hope I am not missing anything.